# Cordova Start.io (ex. StartApp) ads lib

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, startapp

who have experience in creating Cordova plugins - I need your help.

In 2019 Lukas Reiner has created a very good plugin for Ionic (Cordova) to show StartApp ads: https://github.com/lreiner/cordova-plugin-startapp-ads

This plugin still working well, but ads lib is outdated.
I had created a fork of this project: https://github.com/valesios/cordova-plugin-startio-ads
I have done next:

- added current Start.io (ex StartApp) ads lib,
- removed unnecessary permissions,
- renamed imports,
- etc

But, now this fork can show only Banner ads.
This fork does not show Interstitial, Rewarded, Splash, Returner ads.
I do not have enough experience in Android Native to debug it.
I will be glad for any help with updating this fork.

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications on the plugin and it's working, I also added the option to load the Banner before showing it.

https://github.com/itsSoufianeDev/cordova-plugin-startapp-ads

BTW iOS is not working.

(PS: I did a mistake by not forking it, Sorry)

Your are free copy anything from my repo and add it to yours.